# How can I refactor duplicated code that differ only in a function call inside?

Tags: c#, refactoring, code-duplication

I have a utility class (U) which I call from another classes.
Let's day I have these functions inside U:

```
Func1(params):
/*some code*/
funcA(param1,param2)
/*some_code*/

Func2(same params as in Func1):
/*same code as in 1*/
funcB(param1,param2) //same types of params as in funcA
/*same code as in 1*/
```

How can I avoid duplicated code here? I thought about passing a delegate of funcA or B, but the problem is that they are implemented inside the utility class, and I am calling func1/2 from outside, so the caller doesnt know funcA or funcB.
Any ideas? my program is in c# (this code is an abstraction)
Thanks

Comment: I think this question needs work (in general). There is no C# here. You are asking a question about C# and describing it in a made up language without a concrete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extract the common part and pass the delegate from `Func1` and `Func2` respectively.

```
private delegate string PerformOperation(Type1 param1, Type2 param2);

private void CommonFunc(Type1 param1, Type2 param2, PerformOperation operation)
{
    PreSteps();
    operation(param1, param2);
    PostSteps();
}
```

All your methods do is calling `CommonFunc` with the parameters and the delegate

```
public void Func1(Type1 param1, Type2 param2)
{
    CommonFunc(param1, param2, funcA);
}

public void Func2(Type1 param1, Type2 param2)
{
    CommonFunc(param1, param2, funcB);
}
```

Since the `CommonFunc` is `private` the client of your library doesn't need to know `PerformOperation`, nor `funcA` or `funcB`.

Answer (score 0):

I would have said to pass an [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netcore-3.1) or *Delegate* as parameter but as you mentioned that the caller does not know about funcA or FuncB, that is not suitable.
As simple suggestion I would try **Encapsulate** the 2 blocks of code which are duplicated. So, you would end-up having something like this:

```
Func1(params)
{
  EncapsulatedBlockOfCode1();
  funcA(param1,param2);
  EncapsulatedBlockOfCode2();

}   
Func2(same params as in Func1)
{
  EncapsulatedBlockOfCode1();
  funcB(param1,param2) //same types of params as in funcA
  EncapsulatedBlockOfCode2();
}
```

At least this might help you to reduce the duplicated code and see more clearly how you may refactor your code.